# [Shell Script]Fast way to read line by line of file

Tags: shell, readfile

I know people will say use `while`,

as

```
while read line; do
        echo "$line"
done < file
```

but this method will block my web page and I don't know the reason......

Then I use `for` as

```
for line in file
do
        echo $line
done
```

The risk of `for` is there may be spaces in one line, then what I get will be separated by space,

and even I do trick to split the space

like I only need `date` and $query data in one line,

and each line will be 'Wed Nov 19 17:59:24 GMT 2014 12345678'

so I use that kind of code:

```
content=""
count=0
for line in $(cat file); do
        if [ $count -le 5 ]; then
                content=$content$line" "
                count=`expr $count + 1`
        else
                content=$content$line","
                count=0
        fi
done
```

(I want to read each line and be concated with ',')

but the result is when the line is too much, all method of `for` will too slow to load data......

The fast method I use is `cat`, but my `cat` doesn't have parameter as `-A` or other......

and I'm not sure how to use `cat` to display file line by line

And I don't know why I can't use `while`, too.( maybe the reason is it is slower than `for`)

So, is there any other way to display files line by line quickly?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: **but this method will block my web page** I think you need to find the cause of this.

Comment: What language is your webpage written in?

Comment: if the lines with the values you want are labeled, you could use `grep -E 'date=|queryValue=' file > /tmp/date_queryLines` and then process that file (there are other ways, this is just a basic idea). It would help if you included small sample of good/bad data lines found in your `file`. Good luck.

Comment: @anubhava Can you give me some direction about what will cause that? Or maybe that just because it use `while`, though others can use it without problem......( is my code wrong?)
@EtanReisner I use Bash Shell Script.
@shellter I want to read whole file line by line, and show it to my web pages, not to query data I want... or am I misunderstand your method?

Thanks you guys for advising!

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't true answer about my problem, but I think I still use `cat`, and use parser in my client side coding. Since my data each line is simple and easy to parser.

Thanks everyone for helping! And I hope it helps others, too!